# How can I use webhooks in Mattermost to redirect user activities from shared linux box to Mattermost channel

Tags: linux, ubuntu-14.04, slack, mattermost

I'm able to setup Mattermost and can curl through webhooks to send some text message to the Mattermost channel however, I'm not getting any option to get more details on the payload format and keywords.

I want to track the user activities on a linux box like what command are run by which user. Appreciate any help!

Thanks!
Ankit